# vuejs - how to bind a computed attribute from String interpolation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a set of computed data that each one of them returns a url -

```
computed:{
facebookUrl(){return "facebook.com"},
twitterUrl(){return "twitter.com"}
}
```

in the template I have a v-for loop and in each one of the items I have a 'name' (name:"facebook",name:"twitter")

now I wand to bind the computed url for each of them like this (I tried several ways, all end the same) -

```
:href="`${item.name}Url`"
```

but instead of getting the computed value I get only the strings...

and yes, I know I can use a method with param to return the value...

Comment: the value in :href will be something like 'facebookUrl', as a string. You can't create a dynamic function like this.
Create a function (not computed value) that get's name as param, and returns the correct url. (use a if else, or switch case).

Answer (score 1):

You can make one computed that returns a dictionary of urls instead of multiple computeds. Then you can lookup each item's url.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
        name: 'facebook'
      },
      {
        name: 'twitter'
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    urls() {
      return {
        facebookUrl: 'facebook.com',
        twitterUrl: 'twitter.com'
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items">
    {{urls[`${item.name}Url`]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a computed property with a dynamic string.  If you do not want to use a lookup method, you have 2 options.

Add the url to the item.

```
:href="item.url"
```

Return a map from your computed, props, data, etc.

```
:href="urls[item.name]}"

urls(){return {facebook:facebook.com, twitter:’twitter.com’} }
```

Comment: the json is more complex then what I wrote, the computed contains params...

Comment: I made it with a method for now, just wanted to be sure that there isn't a shorter way. tnx.

Comment: Shortest way is to have a map.  That approach is the easiest to maintain and extend also.